# OneToMany relationship without new entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

Using JPA and Hibernate
I have an entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLES")
public class Role implements Serializable 
{
       
   @Column
   private List<String> tubes;    

// another fields .setters, getters  
}
```

Every String in List **tubes** - is one row from another table (TUBES).

Table ROLES has an OneToMany relationship with TUBES.
A can make another Entity **Tubes** and map table TUBES on Entity Tubes. But how I can make this without another entity?

**Edit:**

I made

```
 @ElementCollection
 @CollectionTable(name = "TUBES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
 @Column(name = "tube")
 private ArrayList<String> tubes;
```

Deploy on JBoss. And in runtime I get SQLGrammarException

Query created by JPA is:

> /* SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.name = ? */ select role0_.AA_ID as AA1_0_, role0_.ROLNAME as ROLNAME0_, role0_.role as PID4_0_ from PIDDB_PID_ROLE role0_ where role0_.ROLNAME=?
> 17:17:14,661 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ORA-00904: "ROLE0_"."tube": invalid identifier

Comment: Google for hibernate composite mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@ElementCollection` mapping I think this is what are you looking for.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name="TUBES", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
@Column(name="tube")
private List<String> tubes;
```

**Update:**

```
dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

**Update2:**

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

Comment: This is javax.persistence.ElementCollection. it's part of hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

Comment: here field 'tube' from table 'TUBES'?

Comment: JPA ignoring @CollectionTable annotation. I have next query :: select role0_.AA_ID as AA1_0_, role0_.tube as PID4_0_ from ROLES role0_ where role0_.ROLNAME= ?;

Comment: @user1143825, is table TUBES created with role_id and tube fileds?

Comment: Yes, table TUBES contains field 'role_id' (that is ID of some record from ROLES) and contains another fields

Comment: @user1143825, good so if allyour values are stored what is the problem?

Comment: Query contains:: role0_.tube . tube isn't a field of ROLES. It's field of TUBES. So I get SQLGrammarExc

Comment: This correct. tube column supposed to be part of TUBES table. please post your query.

Comment: Might it be that all your other mapping ara not members of javax.persistence package, because I have this code is running on Oracle production environment. See my Update.

Comment: I have same imports, but from javaee-api version 6 :(

Comment: I think the problem happens becuase you are combining jpa annotation with javaee-api annotation. I've never used javaee-api annotations, but I believe there should be any alternative to @ElementCollection

Comment: Show me your persistance.xml plz

Comment: This is Spring Application, everything is mapped exactly like I wrote you above.

Comment: Problem in my JBoss. I am using JBoss 4.3.0.GA that isn't supporting JPA-2

Comment: I see, I'm always using JPA2, I believe you should open new question regarding @ElementCollection alternative in Jboss.